# How can I implement face recognition in microsoft teams

Tags: python, azure, artificial-intelligence, microsoft-teams, facial-identification

I have been trying to implement an api to integrate with live meeting to face recognize. Not sure if Ms teams allows access to the live video.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Picaso - Could you please let us know which API you have implemented?

Answer (score 0):

We can include [Preciate](https://blog.preciate.com/how-to-use-a-microsoft-teams-app-for-employee-recognition) to our Microsoft Teams to add Employees Recognition and also we have [Recognize](https://recognizeapp.com/microsoft-teams-employee-recognition) which is an extension for Employee Recognition for MS Teams.

Also, we have something called [Face under Cognitive Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/face/) in Microsoft Azure which is used for Identity verification.

We can detect faces using few Clients Library SDK’s and has a guide to Detect and analyze face.
Here is a [quick start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/client-libraries?pivots=programming-language-python&tabs=visual-studio) for using face library with multiple languages such as C#, Go, JavaScript, Python and Rest API.

Comment: Not looking for pre made softwares. If we can connect please let me know

Answer (score 0):

[Device capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/device-capabilities-overview), [Tab Device Permission Demo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/v-abt/tab-coversations/samples/tab-device-permissions/nodejs) - These documentation will help you to capture the images in the video. But there isn't any API to implement face recognition in Microsoft teams.